# Code 43 Windows has stopped the device

Tags: windows, usb

I have RS232-USB cable and OS is win8. It was working properly but now its not working. I dont know why maybe I delete smt. I take error as **Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43) A request for the USB device descriptor failed.**

I tried several methods,

- restart computer
- reinstall drivers
- deleting USB controllers from device manager and restart

none of them is worked. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to power off your computer completely, then turn it back on.( Chances are pretty slim that it will work since you already did a restart)

If that doesn't work roll back your drivers to a previous version and if that doesn't work, do a system restore to undo recent Device Manager changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried these solutions, but still does not working. I hope system restore will work but even it didn't :(

Comment: I dont know how it is happened but I again restart computer and now it works :) I think system restore solved this problem.. Thank you